# Repeating two random number sequences VBA

Tags: vba, excel, random, numbers

I have a module in VBA that calls a class function four times. I need the random number stream to repeat the set of numbers generated for the first two classes for the third and fourth class. Thus before the first and third calls I have placed the following code:

```
Rnd -1
Randomize (RandomSeed)
```

where

```
RandomSeed
```

in this case is set to 3.

Within each class function there are several functions that use random numbers to update the values in certain cells within the workbook. There are also several uses of the

```
Rnd
```

function in the core modules within the class. No calculations or occurrences of the

```
Rnd
```

function occur before the first randomisation point.

This doesn't seem to work, I have the following problems:

1) When I open excel, I run the code and the two streams are different, then I run the code a second time and now they are the same and any code run thereafter produces the same stream (as required). Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this may not work on the first code run?
2) Each time I open excel the code produces different numbers (even after the first run).

Can anyone suggest why this ins't working? I've read somewhere that you shouldn't use more than one randomisation point but this doesn't appear to be causing the problems I've outlined. Any general suggestions would be very helpful. Apologies for not posting the code but there is a large amount, most of which isn't relevant to the problem.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Point#1, very likely either *Rnd -1* or *Randomize* doesn't execute properly before your first call, but execute properly before your third call. I suggest that you check that *RandomSeed* is properly initialized with the debugger.

If everything seems Ok in you code, can you run the first call 2x in order to get rid of the problem (may be a VBA bug...).

Point#2, it is very likely that *Rnd* use a time stamp when excel is launched in order to improve the 'randomness'. If this is the case you can not expect to get the same streams after closing Excel. If you want to have the exact same streams at every launch, generate a random table and save it somewhere in your spreadsheet.

As it's been mentioned in the comments, having details of your code would help getting a better answer (just paste the lines where you call *Rnd* and *Randomize*, don't paste the whole code).